# HTML5 database type table

Tags: database, html

I know how to make a MySQL database table with CFML.  However, I was trying to make an app for my work and they don't have MySQL, PHP, cFML or any other system.  I was wondering if it's possible to make an editable table in html5 that will allow users on other computers to see the information.  i.e.  On your computer in cubicle 1, you enter your name and address.  In my computer in cubicle 2, I hit up the page from our intranet and can see your name and address.

The only type of storage that I could use is MS Access.

Comment: You can not share data between multiple clients talking to a single web application without some sort of central store that both clients can communicate with.  You will need some sort of backend here.  You can't do this purely in HTML5 technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

There is local storage and IndexeDB, but these are isolated for individual browser only.

Cutting-edge versions of Firefox and Chrome have support for WebRTC which among other things allows peer-to-peer data exchange, so if you really wanted to, you could build your own decentralized p2p database on top of that experimental technology, …but it's is going to be *hard*. Much much harder than just installing LAMP on one of the machines.